# Get contact thumbnail

Tags: c#, windows-8

When I use the Live Client Auth sdk, I can get a url to a thumbnail for the currently logged in user. How can I get the equivalent thumbnail for a contact of the user?

I know that the `contact` returned by `new ContactPicker().PickSingleContactAsync()` has a `GetThumbnailAsync` method, but that returns a bitmap and I'd rather just use the url. Is that  possible? Is there a way to get the profile pic for any arbitrary email?

Comment: in what context do you need that thumbnail for storing it in some way or for some kind of UI ?

Comment: I'm making a board game where people can start games with their contacts. I'd like to display the contact picture with the game in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the contact returned by new
>   ContactPicker().PickSingleContactAsync() has a GetThumbnailAsync
>   method, but that returns a bitmap and I'd rather just use the url. Is
>   that possible?

No. See documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br224875.aspx

> Is there a way to get the profile pic for any arbitrary email?

Someone else seems to have resolved this. Check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082001/2012977

Comment: That gives me a way to find the picture for a user id, but I can't get the user id without that user signing in, right?

Comment: You are right. I missed that. Yahoo allow you to use the username only. http://img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php?yids=